# Find the shortest paths in a graph from s to all Vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

Given the following problem :

> Given the directed graph G=(V,E) with the weight function W:V→R , describe an algorithm 
>   that find the shortest paths from S to all other Vertices , where the length of the 
>   path equals to the SUM of all the vertices.You need to change an existing algorithm , 
>   to make that work , so there's no need to write a new algorithm.

Please notice that the weight function is on the Vertices and NOT(!!) on the Edges .
What I was thinking is to change the Bellman-Ford algorithm and change the Relax check to the following :

```
1.if d[v]>d[u]+w[u]
 1.1 d[v] <<--  d[u]+w[u]
 1.2 PI[v] <<-- u
```

I don't think this works good enough , any idea what might be the problem ?

thanks ,Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let `w:V->R` be your weight function.

Create a weightening function: `w':E->R` as follows: `w'(u,v) = w(v)`

Run dijkstra/bellman-ford with w'. let d'[v] be the minimal path's weight to v, according to w'.

Then if the shortest path is `s->u1->u2->...->un->v`, you get: `d'[v] = w'(s,u1) + w'(u1,u2)  + ... + w'(un,v)` [by correctness of dijkstra/bellman fofrd] and thus `d'[v] = w(u1) + w(u2) + ... + w(un) + w(v)` [by definition of w'].

so, at overall you get: `d[v] = w(s) d'[v]` and d[v] is the shortest path for vertices.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Floyd–Warshall_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) is the best starting point. Of course, Wikipedia is down in protest today :).